# Toast.maketext error

Tags: android

the red line below the code appear after writing Toast.LENGHT_LONG

package com.example.neomn.myapplication1;

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
        Button start = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnstartservice );
        Button stop = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnstopservice );


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



 Toast.makeText(this , "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, `Toast.makeText()` first argument required **Application Context** and in your code, `this` reefers to Button's onClickListener class not a context of Activity.

change it with

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Context`, "`this`" is wrong.

**Change:**

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**To:**

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Here is your code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstartservice);
        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstopservice);


        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My First Service Started ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Read more about `Context` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html.

Comment: Please explain properly in your answer about problems not only giving solutions work.  Instead of posting whole unnecessary code, just explain why OP facing problem and whats the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Write following lines

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnstartservice );
Button stop = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnstopservice );
```

in your `OnCreate` method instead of writing them at class level because `start`  and `stop` causes nullpointer as you define those outside of activity lifecycle methods.And also change

```
 Toast.makeText(this , "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

i.e. Rewrite your code as

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstartservice);
        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstopservice);


        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My First Service Started ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

get the context from the view being clicked (use the `v` argument)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Toast.makeText(v.getContext() , "My First Service Started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```